# Subclipse SVN revision number build variable

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I programming in Eclipse and using Subclipse as the SVN plugin. Is there a way to create a build variable in Eclipse which would take on the SVN revision of the current project?

Comment: do you need this build variable for ant build scripts?

Comment: Nope, it's for displaying it as a string in the program.